# Handling lazy-loading webpages using vba

Tags: vba, web-scraping, internet-explorer

After a long try I've been able to create a script in vba which can successfully handle webpages with lazy-load. It can reach the bottom of a slow loading webpage if the hardcoded number of the loop is set accurately. I tried with few such pages and found it working flawlessly. The one I'm pasting below is created using `finance.yahoo` site. It can parse the title of different news after going down to a certain level of that page according to the loop I've defined. Now, what I wanna expect to have is do the same thing without using hardcoded delay what I've already used in my script. Thanks in advance for any guidance to the improvement.

Here is what I've written:

```
Sub Web_Data()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument
    Dim storage As Object, posts As Object

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://finance.yahoo.com/"
        Do While .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop
        Set html = .document
    End With

    Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("00:00:005")

    For scroll_down = 1 To 10
        Set storage = html.getElementsByClassName("StretchedBox")
        html.parentWindow.scrollBy 0, 99999
        Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("00:00:005")
    Next scroll_down

    For Each posts In storage
        Row = Row + 1: Cells(Row, 1) = posts.ParentNode.innerText
    Next posts
    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Reference to add to the library:

```
1. Microsoft Internet Controls
2. Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

Comment: The count of elements for `StretchedBox` increases as you move down the page (when it loads more content). With that site in your code, the unordered list (`class="Mb(0) Ov(h) P(0) Wow(bw)"`) gets extended as end of page is near. Test keep going to end of page resulted 218 entries of "StretchedBox". Perhaps if you want all the headlines, you have to keep scrolling until the number of "StretchedBox" no longer increasing. You may also speed up loading if you disable image loading in the IE.

Comment: Yep it is. What if the number of titles of that page is unknown to me and I wanna run my script to get them all without being sure about how many loops it will take to reach there? Basically, If i increase the number of loop in my existing script, I can achieve what i want but I do not wish to hardcode any number. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to try this below. First is to try reduce loading times, especially images and videos when scrolling down. Then have a counter to count number of "StretchedBox" elements before the scroll down, then check up to a few more attempts until no more changes (I used 5 in code). You can remove the `Debug` lines in final version.

**Note** some "StretchedBox" isn't really an article headline (video related), you will need to work on those to filter out junk.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Web_Data()
    Const TITLES As String = "StretchedBox"
    Dim sh As Object, regval As String

    ' Change IE Options
    Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    regval = "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\Display Inline Images"
    sh.RegWrite regval, "no", "REG_SZ"
    regval = "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\Enable Browser Extensions"
    sh.RegWrite regval, "no", "REG_SZ"
    regval = "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\Play_Animations"
    sh.RegWrite regval, "no", "REG_SZ"
    regval = "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\EnableAlternativeCodec"
    sh.RegWrite regval, "no", "REG_SZ"

    ' Prepare IE
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument
    Dim posts As Object, sText As String
    Dim TitlesCount As Long, NoChangesCount As Integer, Row As Long

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://finance.yahoo.com/"
        Debug.Print Now, "Navigated Start"
        Do Until .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop
        Debug.Print Now, "Navigate Complete"
        Set html = .document
    End With
    NoChangesCount = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    Do
        DoEvents
        Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("00:00:02")
        ' Remove all the annoying video parts
        RemoveVideos html
        TitlesCount = GetClassCount(html, TITLES)
        Debug.Print Now, TitlesCount
        html.parentWindow.scrollBy 0, 99999
        If TitlesCount = GetClassCount(html, TITLES) Then
            NoChangesCount = NoChangesCount + 1
        Else
            NoChangesCount = 0
        End If
    Loop Until NoChangesCount = 5 ' If no changes for some attempts, assume end of dynamic page
    On Error GoTo 0
    Columns("A").ClearContents
    For Each posts In html.getElementsByClassName(TITLES)
        sText = WorksheetFunction.Clean(posts.ParentNode.innerText)
        'sText = Trim(posts.ParentNode.innerText)
        If Len(sText) > 0 Then
            Row = Row + 1
            Cells(Row, 1).Value = sText
        End If
    Next posts
    IE.Quit
    ' Restore IE Options
    regval = "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\Display Inline Images"
    sh.RegWrite regval, "yes", "REG_SZ"
    regval = "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\Enable Browser Extensions"
    sh.RegWrite regval, "yes", "REG_SZ"
    regval = "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\Play_Animations"
    sh.RegWrite regval, "yes", "REG_SZ"
    regval = "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\EnableAlternativeCodec"
    sh.RegWrite regval, "yes", "REG_SZ"
    Set sh = Nothing
End Sub

Private Function GetClassCount(Doc As HTMLDocument, ClassName As String) As Long
    GetClassCount = Doc.getElementsByClassName(ClassName).Length
End Function

Private Sub RemoveVideos(Doc As HTMLDocument)
    Dim oElement As Object
    For Each oElement In Doc.getElementsByClassName("yvp-main")
        oElement.innerHTML = ""
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: The code in your dropbox link uses different method to break - it does stop eventually I believe, as it only breaks when `NumChanges = TitleCount`. With 4 sec wait each iteration, it takes `4 * TitlesCount`, yesterday it has around 210, so you will have to wait 840s (14 minutes)! My code will stop if `TitlesCount` has not been increased 5 times, 2s wait each so, when it reaches the bottom of page, only 10 second is "wasted". Maybe I mislead you with `NumChanges`. I should have used `NoChangesCount`. Code updated.